# How do I align textarea with the same margin according to its width?

Tags: css

I have a group of `textarea`s with a percentage width. The percentage can be any number, and I just use 30 and 25 for example. Wanted results:

- the width of `textarea` can be any % number.
- in every row, the textareas can spread to **full width**, but with an equal margin between them.

I have made a picture to describe what's expected:

[image]

```css
#group1 textarea {width:30%;margin:2px}
#group2 textarea {width:25%;margin:2px}
```

```html
<div id="group1">
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="group2">
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: so, resizing one will resize other siblings?

Comment: No resizing, just re-positioning.

Comment: But if you resize the holder, the size of textarea would be resized because the width are all % values.

Comment: If you do `text-align: center;` on the divs, the margins remain equal, as per the specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This what you are looking for?

```css
#group1 textarea {
  width:30%;
  margin:2px
}
#group2 textarea {
  width:25%;
  margin:2px
}

#group1, #group2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="group1">
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="group2">
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea><textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
   .subMain {
        display: flex;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .TextBox {
        width: 32%;
        margin-right: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
     .TextBox:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    textarea {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        min-height: 80px;
        resize: vertical;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="subMain">
        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="subMain">
        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="subMain">
        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="TextBox">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[ hope it'll help you :::::::::::: let me know if it works]